# Fine tuning MYSQL for best performance

Tags: mysql

I have a database server that runs on 128GB of RAM, 500GB HDD and 10core processor.
I have installed mysqltuner and adjusted all variables as suggested but the MySQL performance improves for only a few hours and then goes back to sluggish performance.
According to `mytop`, i have about 8 slow queries which I doubt can be the cause of this.
Note that this server has only MySQL running.

How best can i further improve/optimize MySQL perfomance. Below is a snippet of mysql.conf file.

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

key_buffer_size     = 128M
max_allowed_packet  = 400M
thread_stack        = 284K
thread_cache_size       = 64

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_file_size = 576M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_checksums = 0

join_buffer_size=500M
sort_buffer_size=4M
read_buffer_size=4M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
table_definition_cache=4096
table_open_cache=4096
tmp_table_size=536870912
optimizer_search_depth=12
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=0
max_heap_table_size=1610612736
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please also post to pastebin.com your complete MySQLTuner.pl report (generated after 24 hours of UPTIME) and your MYTOP results as well as HTOP report.

Comment: Removing these 4 lines 

join_buffer_size=500M
sort_buffer_size=4M
read_buffer_size=4M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M 
from your configuration will produce amazing improvement, proving simple tuning can be beneficial and allow defaults to work in your favor.

Comment: @Wilson, can you help explain how removing them would help? here is the link to the paste https://pastebin.com/DTWvzjQz

Comment: Your requests for 512M requires every CONNECTION to prepare for the specific limits.  Defaults are respectively 256K, 256K, 128K and 256K for a total per CONNECTION of less than 1M of preparation.  Specifically in the case of read_rnd_buffer_size, why read 4M when 256K will improve performance?  You are forcing the system to read 16X the data required to complete the task.  Analysis in process.  Hope to post suggestions for you within 48 hours.

Comment: Benson, Very helpful OS information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for more meaningful server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Benson, Suggestions will be delayed until the OS report for 'ulimit -a' results are posted.  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%open%'; and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%'; reveals high volumes of OPENED activity.  With your additional info, suggestions for your instance can be more accurate for your instance workload. Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section to improve performance

```
tmp_table_size=1610612736  # from 536870912 to match max_heap_table_size and reduce created_tmp_table RPHr of 218
read_rnd_buffer_size=96K  # from 4M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 1,005,923
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 4M to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 2,584,343
net_buffer_length=96K  # from 16K to reduce packet send/receive frequency
```

Observation,
opened_tables count in your status measured at 1,261 per hour.
Providing ulimit -a report from your OS may identify Open Files with too low a limit for your workload.

Please view profile for contact info and FREE tips and Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: @Benson Okello How is your instance performing now?

Answer (score 2):

You can't tune your way out of most performance problems.  Identify the "slow" queries, present them here, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN`.

The slowlog is a good way to discover which are 'worst'.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Meanwhile, what version are you using?  What ENGINE are you using for the tables?  (Hopefully InnoDB for all of your tables.)

Since you have 128GB of RAM, 4G for the buffer pool is much too small; change:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 90G
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16
```

Are you using ENGINE=MEMORY with some huge tables?  If not, change to:

```
max_heap_table_size = 500M
```

Comment: Hi Rick, I'm using version 5.7 and InnoDB. I have adjusted the variables as suggested and I am monitoring the performance.

Comment: @RickJames I believe the question only goes back 4 days.  I could be wrong.

Comment: Benson, Since in 7 days your instance has only had to read 4G of data per innodb_data_read (BYTES) a more reasonable innodb_buffer_pool_size would be 8G.  Also, if you would change innodb_change_buffer_max_size from 25 to 50 (percent) you would expedite completion of innodb_pages_created when needed.  innodb_log_buffer_size from 16M to 200M would reduce frequency of WRITEs to your log to improve performance.  For now innodb_buffer_pool_instances could remain at 4 to work with an 8G buffer pool size.

Answer (score 0):

To suggest you changes in your configuration we should also know current MySQL Status and size of databases.

Try to look at Releem - MySQL Performance Tuning tool. It'll collect metrics from your server and score your current configuration.

Also it can suggest you the performance optimized MySQL configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @WilsonHauck Please try to send email again.

Comment: We didn’t receive email from you. Please try to send us email to hello[at]releem.com. I’ve wrote you in Skype

Comment: Releem does answer emails.  There are some timeout issues causing email to not be delivered to releem.com   Releem will work with their email hosting services to improve reliability when people try to reach them.  Roman, Thank You for your connection today.